# Software as a Service, Content Delivery Networks and how it all fits together

Tags: javascript, cloud, cdn, saas

I'm sure I am running the risk of being told off for being off topic or too vague with this question but after a great deal of research I really don't know where else to start other than the knowledgeable folks on SO.

Here is the general gist of what I want to do:

I have some web software I want to make available to my clients the easiest way possible. From what I have read and understand SaaS is the best option for this. I want to enable customers to sign up, and then copy and paste a segment of code into their site and that is the set up complete. Take this piece of code for example:

```
setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
a.src=document.location.protocol+"myscript.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
```

This is code from another site. But from what I understand it asychronously creates script tags and calls an external javascript file from a CDN and appends this to the users web page?

So, if I am right the user will now have a pointer to a javascript file hosted on a CDN. In this file I want to dynamically generate HTML content specific to the user and then append it to the webpage they are viewing. Say this HTML is a form which submits to a database on the CDN via AJAX.

So this is what I want to do. But it is all new to me. I am not even sure if it possible, and whether SaaS using a CDN is the right approach? If anyone could point me to some tutorials or articles about how to set something like this up it would be great. I have done a great deal of research but am finding it to a bit of a minefield of information. It is difficult to know where to start.

Sorry for such a vague question. I will edit and refine as I receive answers to try and clarify things and hopefully help out some other people.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at Google Tag Manager, as a way to inject tags into your content.